# Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying to order, in a descendant way, a set of values by the date of the update but I'm encountering this weird error:

```
Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies.
```

I'm not sure what it means, I have a similar line with the same code above and it works, not sure if I can't have twice the same grouping code.

```
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY update_timestamp) as id_update
```

I'm expecting it to partition by user_id the different updates that it received.

Answer (score 4):

Found the issue, the grouping key must be part of the query list, that means that the update_timestamp must be part of the select list.

select 
user_id,
**update_timestamp**,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY update_timestamp) as id_update
from table a

Comment: but isn't your grouping key user_id?

Answer (score 0):

You also get this error if you use the LAG function and forget to put parameters into it (because you're so used to ROW_NUMBER having no params)

eg

`LAG() OVER (ORDER BY pos)`